# Android SharedPreference Ghost Number?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, sharedpreferences

I am losing my mind, I am using shared preference to create google maps markers, and it is getting coordinates from a 2130 line long text document but something is really off, here is the coordinates it is getting around line 1982

```
06-16 23:23:10.072  22228-22228/com.emiliogaines.fuelfinder D/X:﹕ 12.0434 990
06-16 23:23:10.072  22228-22228/com.emiliogaines.fuelfinder D/Y:﹕ 57.7891
06-16 23:23:10.130  22228-22228/com.emiliogaines.fuelfinder D/X:﹕ 17.8537 991
06-16 23:23:10.130  22228-22228/com.emiliogaines.fuelfinder D/Y:﹕ 59.4185
06-16 23:23:10.169  22228-22228/com.emiliogaines.fuelfinder D/X:﹕ 35 992
06-16 23:23:10.169  22228-22228/com.emiliogaines.fuelfinder D/Y:﹕ 16.403
06-16 23:23:10.202  22228-22228/com.emiliogaines.fuelfinder D/X:﹕ 60.2867 993
06-16 23:23:10.202  22228-22228/com.emiliogaines.fuelfinder D/Y:﹕ 16.8904
06-16 23:23:10.230  22228-22228/com.emiliogaines.fuelfinder D/X:﹕ 60.6137 994
```

(the end number is the line-number divided by 2)

and here is the EXACT same part but from the text file

```
12.0434
57.7891
17.8537
59.4185
16.403
60.2867
16.8904
60.6137
```

somehow it gets the number 35 and it messes up the whole system as you can see

and this is the code retrieving the text

```
        while(linecordx != null){

            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(linecordx), Double.parseDouble(linecordy)))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.okq8_scale))
                    .title(statoilid + ". OKQ8")
                    .snippet("Tryck på den här rutan för att ändra Markören"));
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorsave = sharedPreferences.edit();

            editorsave.putInt("Title" + statoilid, statoilid);
            editorsave.putString("Info" + statoilid, "Tryck på den här rutan för att ändra Markören");
            editorsave.putString("XCord"+statoilid, linecordx);
            editorsave.putString("YCord" + statoilid, linecordy);
            editorsave.putString("Icon" + statoilid, "5");
            editorsave.commit();
            statoilid++;
            statoilnumber++;
            linecordx = okreader.readLine();
            linecordy = okreader.readLine();
                Log.d("X: ", linecordx + " "+ statoilid);
            Log.d("Y: ", linecordy);



        }
    } catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you get tunnel vision with these kind of things but I did see something immediately.

> 59.4185 ends with 5
>
> 16.403 ends with 3 (it's also strangely only 3 decimals)
>
> = 35

I'm pretty sure your readLine() methods are to blame, you probably initialized them incorrectly somehow. I would also try changing the numbers in the file surrounding those lines slightly to see what goes wrong.

Comment: Hm, I changed the value on those lines, restarted program, it works! Then I changed them back and restarted program and it works. Hm, must've been a bugg or something, thanks!